# Regex for repeated words with punctuation

Tags: regex

I want to check for duplicated words right next to each other, but even if there is punctuation in between.

For example:

```
Vivamus Vivamus diam, diam, Vivamus Vivamus diam, diam Vivamus
```

There should be four distinct hits here.

I can't figure out why this isn't working. Why? What should the correct code be?

```
(\w*(?:[ ,\.])*?)\1
```

---

*PS: This is* ***not*** *necessarily for the Perl engine.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `(?:` is a non-capturing parenthesis, meaning it won't store the matches.  You will need to use capturing parentheses.

```
(\w+)\W+\1
```

Answer (score 1):

`[[\w|\W]+ ]+` worked for me. Breakdown:

`\w`: word character

`\W`: non-word character

`[\w|\W]+`: each character may be a word or non-word character and repeated one or more times

`[[\w|\W]+ ]+`: ...appended with a space at some point, all occurring one or more times

Answer (score 0):

The original expression doesn't create a separate capture for the punctuation, but does include the captured punctuation in the first capture.  That means it would spot things like:

```
diam, diam, really, really, twice.
```

But you aren't really interested in the punctuation, so [TJ L's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213824/63550) works properly, even though the '(?: ) is a non-capturing parenthesis' explanation is somewhat ... incomplete?  The comment quoted is accurate, but it isn't why the overall regex failed.