# Count repetitive words in string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, count

I have a string:

```
"Hi, hi Jane! I'm so. So glad to to finally be able to write - WRITE!! - to you!"
```

and i need to count pairs of repetitive words.

```
def repetitionEncryption(letter):
    pattern = ???
    regex = re.compile(???)
    return len(re.findall(regex, letter))
```

Thank You for attention.

Comment: You'd like us to provide you with a regex instead of "????" ?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Yes,sir. I need to solve this tans only by changing "???"

Comment: Regex is not made for that

Comment: @KillerDeath How so? You can create **recursive regex**, see the answer I linked to above.

Comment: The answer from this link don't working for my cases

Comment: Then you need to provide examples of the desired result, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: @AvoAsatryan I beg to differ: https://regex101.com/r/PLxLSi/1

Comment: @ctwheels, that is not what he wants to do.

Comment: Then the user should clarify what they want to do, because all the user mentioned is to *catch repetitive words* - which https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823037/3600709 does exactly

Comment: i need to count repetitive words, but cases of this words may differ. for exaple :write - WRITE!!

Comment: Like this: `\b(\w+)[^\w]+\1\b`? https://regex101.com/r/BCwpWO/1

Comment: repetetive words anywhere within string or one after the other? If Jane repeats anywhere within string, then it is one more repetitive word to count?

Comment: situation of this words isn't important for this task

Comment: @AvoAsatryan if you're looking for repetition throughout the whole string then Coldspeed has your answer. If you're looking for immediate repetition (one word after the other) then `\b(\w+)[^\w]+\1\b` https://regex101.com/r/BCwpWO/1 (as per my previous comment) is your answer (note the modifier `i` so that it's case insensitive)

Comment: @ctwheels, if Jane appears anywhere else in the string, your regex will not catch it. It relies on non word character separator, one or more of them actually

Comment: @KillerDeath you didn't read my last comment which explains my answer and coldstone's answer. The question is fairly broad when the word *repetition* is used. The user never specified immediate repetition vs full string repetition

Comment: He said: situation of this words isn't important for this task

Comment: @KillerDeath After I posted my potential answer

Comment: @ctwheels yes, that is true.

Comment: Note that this was already marked a duplicate (but of an incorrect question). I changed it to reflect the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Note that question was already marked a duplicate by Community (but of an incorrect question). I changed it to reflect the correct one.</sub>

---

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333681/regex-repeated-words-on-the-same-line) tagged with JavaScript, but needs a little modification for python.

```
import re

text = "Hi, hi Jane! I'm so. So glad to to finally be able to write - WRITE!! - to you!"
repeats = re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)', text, re.I)
print(repeats)
['Hi', 'so', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'write']

repeats = list(map(str.lower, repeats))
```

Now, create a counter.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(repeats)
print(c)
Counter({'Hi': 1, 'so': 1, 'to': 3, 'write': 1})
```

Or, more primitively:

```
r_set = set(repeats)
c = {w : repeats.count(w) for w in r_set} 
print(c)
{'hi': 1, 'so': 1, 'to': 3, 'write': 1}
```

The values of the keys are the number of repeats. If the value of `'Hi'` is 1, that means `'Hi'` occurred twice. And so on.

---

The regex is

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

Details

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+)` - capturing group for a word
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=.*\b\1\b)` - lookahead, consisting of

  - `.*` anything
  - `\b\1\b` the same word captured in the first group. Here, `\1` is the reference to the first group.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to split the sentence up into an array and the compare each item in the array. You wouldn't be using regex. With regex you need to know what you are looking for ahead of time. Say you want to know how many times 'Jane' is in the sentence.

Comment: Yes, i can write such a code. but i can only use regex in this task

Comment: This is a homework?

Comment: Seems like it now, Killer Death